# Get value from a nested object via agreggate from mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a simmilar list :

```
[
  { 
     origin: 'asdf',
     translation: { ru: 'asdf' },
     _id: '215efb05-eb01-4376-8da2-8d8960a0e46d' 
  }
]
```

query to mongoose:

```
await LessonPhrase.aggregate([
   { $match: { lessonId } },
   { $project: {
      _id: '$_id',
      origin: 1,
      translation: '$.ru'
   }}
]);
```

I want to get following list:

```
[
    { 
       origin: 'asdf',
       translation: 'asdf',
       _id: '215efb05-eb01-4376-8da2-8d8960a0e46d' 
    }
 ]
```

but getting error every time, cant handle it..

Comment: Could you show us what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dollar sign (`$`) in `$project` stage represents a reference to your document's root so to get `ru` from nested `transaction` object you need:

```
await LessonPhrase.aggregate([
      { $match: { lessonId } },
      { $project: {
          _id: '$_id',
          origin: 1,
          translation: '$translation.ru'
      } }
  ]);
```